# How can I fix the size of randomly 5 generated numbers?

Tags: java, random

I am randomly generating numbers using `java.util.Random`. But, I can not keep the length of the numbers fixed. Can you help me please?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i'm trying to generate a random number between 1 and 5 with  15 characters in length

Comment: What do you mean by 'length'?  15 points after the decimal point?

Comment: like 123451234512345 but randomly

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried (that could be added to the question).  Given a mistake in one of the answers so far, this could also be *your* mistake (you can't hold 15 digits in an int) - that the problem isn't with the random numbers at all.

Answer (score 3):

To fix the length of a randomly generated number, generally you'll want to fix the random number generation to a range. For instance, if you'd like to generate a 6 digit long random number, you'll want numbers from `100,000` to `999,999`. You can achieve this by using the following formula.

```
Random r = new Random();
int randomNum = r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```

Where `max` is the maximum number, such as `999999`, and `min` is your minimum number, such as `100000`.

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment, I see that you're trying to generate a 15-digit number containing only 1-5 inclusive. Here is a simple way to do this:

```
import java.util.Random;

StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
Random r = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    s.append(r.nextInt(5) + 1);
}

System.out.println("The random number is: " + s.toString());
```

As noted by @MichaelT, a 15 digit number will not fit in an integer. If you need to perform an operation on it, you should store it in a long.

```
long randomLong = Long.valueOf(s.toString()).longValue();
```

Comment: I wanted to generate something like this 123451234512345 with min = 1 and max = 5 with a length of 15 characters

Comment: Please note that a 15 digit number will *not* fit in an int.  You will likely get an NumberFormatException there.

Comment: No problem! If this resolved your issue, please consider marking this  answer as the _accepted_ answer for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than thinking of generating an integer, think in terms of generating a String of 15 digits, each in the required range.

You can use nextInt(int) to pick each digit.

Comment: Yes the result should be a string of values

Comment: @user2970322 a *string* of values? are you going to use this as a String? or as a number?

Comment: I mean generate a random number between 1 and 5 and append the next random number to the first one till the 15 characters length.

Comment: @user2970322 you mention *number* and then you mention *character* in length.  Do you want a *number* that is 15 *digits* long (only using the digits 12345) or do you want a *string* of *characters* 15 characters long (only using the characters 12345).  This is a rather important distinction.

Comment: i just want to concatenate them

Comment: It is easy to switch between the String and number views. For example, generate a String and use it to create a BigInteger. It is going to be easier to generate it treating it as a String.

Comment: like first the program generate a random number then the second time concatenate the second one to the first one for example first random number is 1 and the second is 2 after that i should have something like 12 and so on till something like 123451234512345 (15 characters)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to consider is that an `int` cannot hold 15 digits.  It just can't.  It can only go up to 2<sup>32</sup> -1, which is 9 digits long.  A `long` can hold up to 19 digits - but if one wants to solve for the general case, it is necessary to use the `BigInteger` package instead.

Remember that BigInteger is an immutable object (like String) and thus you must assign the value back when looping.

```
package com.michaelt.so.random15;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        BigInteger result = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            result = result.multiply(BigInteger.TEN)
                           .add(BigInteger.valueOf(r.nextInt(5)+1));
        }
        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }
}
```

It starts out with the value ZERO, and loops through for 15 times, each time first multiplying the value by 10 (another BigInteger preallocated value) and then adds the new value into the 1's position.  It does this 15 times.

When done, one can get its value as a string or long or other format - or continue to use it as a BigDecimal (necessary if you should ever decide you want a 20 digit long value).

Runs of the above code produce output such as:

```
313455131111333
245114532433152
531153533113523
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok using libraries:

```
RandomStringUtils.random(15, "12345")
```

would give you Strings like: 124444211351355 of length 15

I just happened to write a post about that (shameless self-advertising link: http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/generating-random-numbers-strings-java/)